# FPGA synthesis a clock gating cell to a LUT not LDCE + AND?

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx

I want to synthesize a clock gating cell in Verilog code like this:

```
reg clk_en_i;
always @(clk_in or clk_en)begin
  if(!clk_in)
    clk_en_i <= clk_en;
end
assign clk_out= clk_in&clk_en_i;
```

but after FPGA synthesizing, the gating function is fail. I watched the netlist schematic by Vivado and found the synplify synthesized the clock gating cell to a LUT6 cell: [LUT6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vgCn.png)

It's not a glitch free gating cell! That's why the function is fail!

I tried to probe the internal signal by Identify, but after FPGA synthesizing, the function is correct! And I watched the netlist schematic again: [LDCE+AND](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOXjE.png)

The same Verilog code produces different synthesizing results. Why? I'm sure LUT6 is the wrong logic result. Can someone explain this weird situation?

Comment: What does "found the synplify systhesis" mean?

Comment: For glitch free switching see this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/352464/what-does-it-mean-to-gate-the-clock

Comment: My synthesis tool is  "synopsis synplify"

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!clk_en)
  clk_en_i <= clk_en;
```

This looks suspicious. You update `clk_en_i` as soon as `clk_en` drops, regardless of `clk_in` state.

Perhaps, you should change `clk_en_i` when `clk_in` is low. Like:

```
if(!clk_in)
  clk_en_i = clk_en;
```

Comment: Oh, Sorry! You are right! My original verilog code is as you say!

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I corrected my Verilog code in my post.